# Arcgis for Android 10.2 mapView zoom out level

Tags: android, arcgis

I need to zoom out my map. I have tried --mMapView.zoomout();-- but it only zoom out 1 level, I want to zoom out further. I know can do in .xml --mapoptions.ZoomLevel="5"-- but I wanted to put in my Activity Class. Some guides is needed, thank you very much.

Comment: More details would help, including some code. What library are you using exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MapOptions option = new MapOptions(MapOptions.MapType type);
// Sets zoom level.
option.setZoom(int zoom);

// Switches basemap by the given options.
mMapView.setMapOptions(MapOptions options);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, Best way to handle zoom with animation,Even, it will work nice if you add any other layer like "One Map".

```
/* set zoom level */

double LEVEL=5;

mMapView.centerAt(lat, lng, false);
mMapView.setScale(ZOOM_LEVEL, true);
```

if you want to show current location with proper Zooming use below code

```
mMapView.getLocationDisplayManager().setAutoPanMode(LocationDisplayManager.AutoPanMode.LOCATION);

mMapView.getLocationDisplayManager().start();
```